# Inline-block vertical-align middle extra spacing issue

Tags: css

Line-height is 24px, but the parent element now have 25px height.

My question is why the parent element (block, inline-block or table) will have a extra vertical spacing when a inline-block come with `vertical-align: middle`?

How can i fixed this issue without `float` or `flexbox`? Thanks.

```js
$('span').after($('.block').css('height'));
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 24px;
}

.block {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  .block
</div>

<span>.block height: </span>
```

Comment: Your inline-blocks are vertically aligned with the line strut and the space characters between the inline-blocks which are aligned by their baselines. How you fix it depends on why you're vertically aligning those boxes by their middles, since the only effect of doing so in your sample is to increase the line-height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seams to fix the issue

```js
$('span').after($('.block').css('height'));
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 24px;
}

.block {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 1; //remove space
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  line-height: 24px; //set line-height
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    .inline-block
  </div>
  .block
</div>

<span>.block height: </span>
```

Comment: TLDR `line-height: 1` fixes the issue.